# How to convert tokens (octal representation in strings)

Tags: java

How to know what "\141\142\163\164\162\141\143\164" represent in literal token characters and what is "@"?

```
public static final String[] jjstrLiteralImages = {
"", null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null,
"\141\142\163\164\162\141\143\164", "\142\157\157\154\145\141\156", "\142\162\145\141\153", "\142\171\164\145", 
"\143\141\163\145", "\143\141\164\143\150", "\143\150\141\162", "\143\154\141\163\163", 
"\143\157\156\163\164", "\143\157\156\164\151\156\165\145", "\144\145\146\141\165\154\164", 
"\144\157", "\144\157\165\142\154\145", "\145\154\163\145", 
"\145\170\164\145\156\144\163", "\146\141\154\163\145", "\146\151\156\141\154", 
"\146\151\156\141\154\154\171", "\146\154\157\141\164", "\146\157\162", "\147\157\164\157", "\151\146", 
"\151\155\160\154\145\155\145\156\164\163", "\151\155\160\157\162\164", "\151\156\163\164\141\156\143\145\157\146", 
"\151\156\164", "\151\156\164\145\162\146\141\143\145", "\154\157\156\147", 
"\156\141\164\151\166\145", "\156\145\167", "\156\165\154\154", "\160\141\143\153\141\147\145", 
"\160\162\151\166\141\164\145", "\160\162\157\164\145\143\164\145\144", "\160\165\142\154\151\143", 
"\162\145\164\165\162\156", "\163\150\157\162\164", "\163\164\141\164\151\143", "\163\165\160\145\162", 
"\163\167\151\164\143\150", "\163\171\156\143\150\162\157\156\151\172\145\144", "\164\150\151\163", 
"\164\150\162\157\167", "\164\150\162\157\167\163", "\164\162\141\156\163\151\145\156\164", 
"\164\162\165\145", "\164\162\171", "\166\157\151\144", "\166\157\154\141\164\151\154\145", 
"\167\150\151\154\145", "\163\164\162\151\143\164\146\160", "\141\163\163\145\162\164", null, null, 
null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, "\50", "\51", "\173", "\175", 
"\133", "\135", "\73", "\54", "\56", "\75", "\76", "\74", "\41", "\176", "\77", "\72", 
"\75\75", "\74\75", "\76\75", "\41\75", "\174\174", "\46\46", "\53\53", "\55\55", "\53", 
"\55", "\52", "\57", "\46", "\174", "\136", "\45", "\74\74", "\76\76", "\76\76\76", 
"\53\75", "\55\75", "\52\75", "\57\75", "\46\75", "\174\75", "\136\75", "\45\75", 
"\74\74\75", "\76\76\75", "\76\76\76\75", };
```

Comment: If anyone has a similar problem here is [the table for conversion](http://www.csgnetwork.com/asciiset.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pretty simple:

```
 System.out.println("\141\142\163\164\162\141\143\164");  // first String
```

result: `abstract`

---

A one-liner:

```
 for(String s:jjstrLiteralImages) if (s!=null) System.out.println(s);
```

---

The escaped values in the String are **octal** representations of the ASCII values:

```
 /141 = 97 = 'a'
```

**Further reading:**

- [Java Language Specification, 3.10.6 Escape Sequences for Character and String Literals](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/lexical.html#3.10.6)

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(new String[] { /* your array here */ }));
```

Output:

> [, null, null, null, null, null, null,
>   null, null, null, null, null, null,
>   null, abstract, boolean, break, byte,
>   case, catch, char, class, const,
>   continue, default, do, double, else,
>   extends, false, final, finally, float,
>   for, goto, if, implements, import,
>   instanceof, int, interface, long,
>   native, new, null, package, private,
>   protected, public, return, short,
>   static, super, switch, synchronized,
>   this, throw, throws, transient, true,
>   try, void, volatile, while, strictfp,
>   assert, null, null, null, null, null,
>   null, null, null, null, null, null, (,
>   ), {, }, [, ], ;, ,, ., =, >, <, !, ~,
>   ?, :, ==, <=, >=, !=, ||, &&, ++, --,
>   +, -, *, /, &, |, ^, %, <<, >>, >>>, +=, -=, *=, /=, &=, |=, ^=, %=, <<=, >>=, >>>=]

(Sounds like the reserved keywords of the java language)

Reference:

[Arrays.toString(Object[])](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString%28java.lang.Object%5b%5d%29) is a helper method to generate the toString() representation of an array's elements. There is also [Arrays.deepToString(Object[])](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#deepToString%28java.lang.Object%5b%5d%29) that performs the same task recursively on nested arrays.

---

On a side note:

I tried to sort the output and remove nulls, but it doesn't get any shorter than this:

```
final Set<String> set=
    new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(arr));
set.remove(null);
System.out.println(new TreeSet<String>(set));
```

Or:

```
final List<String> list =
    new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(arr));
while(list.remove(null)){}
Collections.sort(list);
System.out.println(list);
```

Does anybody have a shorter version?

Comment: I use http://www.asciitable.com/ for reference. @ is `\u0040` (unicode hex) , `\100` (octal) and `&#64;` (HTML entity)

Answer (score 0):

Those look like escaped characters that are just the corresponding ASCII values.  Try finding a list of ASCII codes and comparing.

Comment: hmm so "\46\75" with this table http://www.petefreitag.com/cheatsheets/ascii-codes/ means ".K". This is not logic for me

Comment: "\141\142\163\164\162\141\143\164" must mean "abstract" but with ascii 141 is �

Comment: @Juve: the numbers are octal numbers (i.e. base-8 and not base-10) as described [by the JLS §3.10.6](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/lexical.doc.html#101089). Note that those octal escapes are very rarely used in Java, unicode escapes (`\uXXXX`) are much more common.